# How do I select dates from a read-only react calendar without clicking?

Tags: javascript, c#, python, reactjs, selenium

I am trying to performing scraping on a website which has a react-calendar datepicker, the input box is read-only (i.e. I can only select dates using the calendar) and even when I could alter the dates through executing javascript, it doesn't read in the dates that have been input, when I press the "OK" button

[image: calendar]

I have tried changing the .readOnly to false and edit the dates using JS as suggested by another stackoverflow post, but when I press the "OK" button it still doesn't read in the dates I put in.

I have also tried changing the 'datetime' element on one of the calendar buttons for clicking to try to get my desired date:

original:

```
<time datetime="2019-11-07T00:00:00.000">7</time>
```

editted:

```
<time datetime="2018-09-07T00:00:00.000">7</time>
```

But after clicking it still uses the original date.

From some trial and error using Google Console, the 'OK' button is bound to another JS file

```
PostFilterDateRangeSelect.jsx:71 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of null
    at t.value (PostFilterDateRangeSelect.jsx:71)
    at onClick (PostFilterDateRangeSelect.jsx:117)
    at Object.o (react-dom.production.min.js:15)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.production.min.js:16)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.production.min.js:16)
    at u (react-dom.production.min.js:20)
    at d (react-dom.production.min.js:22)
    at f (react-dom.production.min.js:22)
    at b (react-dom.production.min.js:21)
    at O (react-dom.production.min.js:24)
    at h (react-dom.production.min.js:24)
    at xe (react-dom.production.min.js:82)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.production.min.js:186)
    at Q (react-dom.production.min.js:42)
    at He (react-dom.production.min.js:84)
    at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.production.min.js:187)
```

Relevant code from the PostFilderDateRangeSelect JS file:

```js
applyCustomDate(e){
    if(this.props.initialValues.from && this.props.initialValues.to){
        this.props.applyCustomDate(e);
    }else{
        if(!this.props.initialValues.from){
            this.setState({
                showFromError: true
            })
        }
        if(!this.props.initialValues.to){
            this.setState({
                showToError: true
            })
        }
   }
}
```

How do I change the value of the date without clicking the react calendar?

Comment: @Bradz The textbox doesn't allow me to type anything, I tried changing the value using Google Console through: $('input[id="date-from').value = "12 Nov 2016"  ; I am able to change the value but when I click the 'OK' button, the console threw an error as posted in the question

Comment: Tried removing the readonly attribute, when I press the "OK" button it still doesn't read in my input and threw the same error - I think there is a backend value stored for the date while the textbox is only for the user to read

Comment: I guess you have tried all possible hacks, probable way is a dev to the rescue.